# Проверка данных в вычисляемой ячейке

Tags: excel

[image: Пример таблицы]

Я пытаюсь сделать проверку данных в ячейке B4, которая должна выводить ошибку в случае превышения лимита в ячейке B1 (например, 1000).

Для этого в ячейке B4 в настройках "Данные" -> "Проверка данных" выбираю проверку вводимых значений "Целое число", которое не должно превышать значение ячейки B1 (т.е. 1000) и настраиваю вывод сообщения об ошибке.

После чего, если вручную в ячейку B4 ввести число больше 1000 - выдается ошибка, но если ввести данные в ячейки B2 и B3 (например, 500 и 600), то проверка не выполняется (не выдается ошибка о превышении лимита в 1000 в ячейке B4.

Подскажите, как сделать проверку данных в вычисляемой ячейке?

Comment: Что значит "вычисляемая"? Ячейка В1 упоминается ошибочно или ошибка здесь: *ошибка о превышении лимита в 1000 в ячейке* **B4**?

Comment: "Вычисляемая" - значит в этой ячейке (B4) вычисляется значение по формуле B2 + B3, а не просто вручную вводится значение. 
Проверка данных в ячейке B4 осуществляется не на конкретное число, а на значение, не превышающее значение в ячейке B1, т.е. на 1000.

Comment: формулой то с условным форматированием не пойдет? надо через проверку данных именно?

Comment: Да в принципе без разницы, глобальный смысл в том, чтобы в таблице, по которой рассчитывается премия, в которой есть много работников,  был установлен лимит на денежные средства (например 100 работников и лимит 100 000 рублей, т.е. каждому работнику будет выделено по 1000 рублей, но если одному из них указать премию больше, то должно сработать "исключение" и вывестись ошибка...)

Comment: Залить ядовитым цветом ячейку с помощью условного форматирования:  =или(диапазон_премий>1000)

Comment: 99 работников получат премию по 100 руб, а один - 2000 руб. Лимит  100 000 не превышен... Нужен контроль лимита общего или контролировать лимит на 1 премию?

Comment: Нужен контроль общего лимита, который складывается из премий отдельных работников

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверку надо ставить на тех ячейках которые изменяете, т.е. на `B2:B3`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда при попытке изменить значения в этих ячейках, формулы будут пересчитаны и выполнена проверка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, для малого количества ячеек, где можно применить ограничение, это подойдет. Но проблема возникнет, если таких ячеек много и они расположены в разных таблицах...

Comment: Странно, я одновременно применил настройку "Проверка данных" для ячеек B2,B3, в  B4 вычисляется B2+B3), но вывод сообщения об ошибке происходит через раз. Так, в ячейке B2 я вписываю 500, в ячейке B3 - 600 и "Сообщение об ошибке" не выводится. Вывод ошибки начинается только после того, когда выполнив указанные вами действия, я снова изменяю значение в ячейке B2 на **любое** число. Т.е. алгоритм действий такой: B2 = 500, B3 = 600 -> ENTER. Далее перехожу в ячейку B2 и когда изменяю её на любое число, **даже** которое дает в сумме с ячейкой B3 меньшее значение, чем в ячейке B1, выводится ошибка.

Comment: >> *таких ячеек много и они расположены в разных таблицах* - свести нужные в один диапазон. Не получается - что-то не так сделали. Ссылки на ячейки закреплены?

Comment: Спасибо, видимо из-за того, что не закрепил ссылки не сработало. После закрепления - всё ок.
А если свести все ячейки в один диапазон (например таких ячеек будет несколько десятков в разных таблицах), а после чего нужно будет добавить ещё одного работника для расчета премий, диапазон нужно будет "сводить" заново? или есть вариант добавить одну ячейку в диапазон?

Comment: @PanChous закрепить нужно только в формуле там где проверка данных т.е. ячейку лимит и результат, т.е. формула `=$B$4<=$B$1` (абсолютная адресация) а вот эту проверку надо ставить во всех ячейках которые вы изменяете, можно с диапазоном и без (если на других листах, то надо еще добавить в формулу название листа вначале `Лист1!$B$4` например). При вставке дополнительных строк, правила проверки тоже копируются, т.е. дополнительно ничего не надо

Answer (score 1):

Положительный эффект от применения *Проверки данных* - запрет ввода значений, сумма которых превысит лимит. И если цель - жесткое ограничение ввода, то это самое оно. Но такой вариант имеет и недостаток.

Пример. Лимит - 100 для суммы двух значений. Вписали первое - 70. Нужно вписать второе - 40. Да, на двух значениях можно увидеть, что сначала нужно уменьшить первое, чтобы второе не вызвало превышения лимита. А если суммируемых много? Пытаемся вписать число, *Проверка данных* запрещает, переходим к другой ячейке, исправляем, возвращаемся, чтобы вписать 40...

Если достаточно индикации состояния, можно применить **Условное форматирование**. В таком варианте можно видеть остаток/превышение лимита и, при необходимости, менять/"перетасовывать" премии.

Ячейка `D1` залита зеленым цветом, в ячейке формула:

```
=ВЫБОР(ЗНАК(B1-B2)+2;
          "Сумма средств превышает лимит на "&ТЕКСТ(B2-B1;"# ##0");
          "Сумма выделенных средст равна лимиту";
          "Остаток премиального фонда "&ТЕКСТ(B1-B2;"# ##0"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Закладка *Главная-Условное форматирование-Создать правило-Использовать формулу*:

```
=$B$2>$B$1
```

Условный формат: белый жирный текст на красном фоне. Форматирование применено в к двум ячейкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Про неудобство в случае подсчета премий у большого количества работников я не подумал! Действительно, скорее всего, предложенный Вами вариант, будет удобнее.
Но, как я понял, решить проблему с ограничением на вычисляемом поле через настройку "Проверка данных" не представляется возможным, что странно и не логично, на мой взгляд =)

Comment: В ответе @Tunker предложено использование этого инструмента.. Но Проверка данных проверяет данные там (в той ячейке), где этот инструмент применен и контролирует "ручной" ввод. На другие ячейки проверка не распространяется. А вот Условное форматирование может ссылаться на другие ячейки, без ссылок на свое значение

Comment: Почему-то вариант, предложенный @Tunker не работает (проблему описал в комментарии к ответу @Tunker). Возможно я в чём-то ошибся... но адекватно у меня не заработало =(
Ну и плюс, если будет большое количество работников в разных таблицах, такой вариант очень трудоемкий...